# QtPropertyBrowser compile error in VS2019

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying to integrate source code of QtPropertyBrowser (based on Qt 5.15.0) into my own VS2019 project, but some errors occurred when compile:

```
1>E:\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\x64\Debug\moc\moc_qtbuttonpropertybrowser.cpp(94,29): error C2027: use of undefined type 'QtButtonPropertyBrowserPrivate'
1>E:\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\qtpropertybrowser\qtbuttonpropertybrowser.h(47): message : see declaration of 'QtButtonPropertyBrowserPrivate'
1>E:\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\x64\Debug\moc\moc_qtbuttonpropertybrowser.cpp(95,29): error C2027: use of undefined type 'QtButtonPropertyBrowserPrivate'
1>E:\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\qtpropertybrowser\qtbuttonpropertybrowser.h(47): message : see declaration of 'QtButtonPropertyBrowserPrivate'
1>E:\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\x64\Debug\moc\moc_qtbuttonpropertybrowser.cpp(96,29): error C2027: use of undefined type 'QtButtonPropertyBrowserPrivate'
1>E:\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\qtpropertybrowser\qtbuttonpropertybrowser.h(47): message : see declaration of 'QtButtonPropertyBrowserPrivate'
1>E:\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\QtPropertyBrowserDemo\x64\Debug\moc\moc_qtpropertybrowser.cpp(377,29): error C2027: use of undefined type 'QtAbstractPropertyBrowserPrivate'
```

I was stucked here for days, could you help me out?

I pushed my project onto GitHub, you can pull it if you wish.

Address here: https://github.com/LiangZuoting/QtPropertyBrowserDemo

Comment: thanks for you attention, i've got a solution from here https://forum.qt.io/topic/119401/how-to-compile-source-code-of-qtpropertybrowser-by-vs2019-correctly/3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add the Qt paths. I think that You should add the path below to your project property:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include
```

I use visual studio 2017 to compile your code, and it works correctly. But I suggest you use QtCreator to develop your program.

Comment: could you fork my project and commit your changes please? so i can compare difference.i added qt path and it didnt work.i notice you use different vs and qt version,maybe that's the point.

Comment: Ok, see your github pull request please.

Comment: thank you, i will try your proposal right now. BTW, i got a right answer based on my environment, https://forum.qt.io/topic/119401/how-to-compile-source-code-of-qtpropertybrowser-by-vs2019-correctly/3

Comment: i compared your repo with mine, you truly only add qt path, so it didnt work on vs2019.thank you all the same.

Comment: I'm very sorry.